# Usando o comando Save do Spring data

Tags: spring-data

Ao usar o comando `save` do Spring Data para fazer o insert na tabela, eu sou obrigado a anotar todas os campos na classe modelo com o anotation `@Column`?

> Caso os campos que eu não anotei aceitem nulos, ele salvaria os campos
>   restantes como nulo?

---

> Caso os campos que eu não anotei não aceitam nulos ele não vai
>   funcionar?

Comment: com o save do spring data ele insere por objeto, e se aquele meu objeto não tem anotado todos os columns da tabela, essa é a duvida, por exemplo na minha tabela eu tenho um campo que aceita nulo e não anotei ele na classe, provavelmente ele vai dar erro porque ele não aceita nulo, eu teria que anotar ele na classe e atribuir um valor a ele antes de mandar o comando save gravar o meu objeto, certo ?? ou errado ?

a duvida é, se o campo não anotado aceitar nulo o que acontece, dá erro também, ou ele é preenchido automaticamente com nulo ?

Comment: Não vai dar erro, se não houver restrição na base de dados será atribuído o valor null normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa anotar necessariamente todos os seus atributos com `@Column`.

Caso opte por não anotar a aplicação irá adotar o padrão do nome do atributo como sendo o nome da coluna na base de dados e se o atributo for um tipo objeto (ex: Integer, Boolean) irá aceitar **nulo** normalmente. Caso utilize primitivo (int, boolean) você precisará garantir que esses valores estejam preenchidos antes de realizar a persistência.

No SO em inglês tem uma resposta interessante no que se refere a utilização de objetos ou tipo primitivo. Veja se ajuda na tomada de decisão: [Which one to use, int or Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423704/which-one-to-use-int-or-integer/423718#423718)